# Restore old Belkin UPS?

Tags: ups

I have an old Belkin F6C650-USB-MAC UPS which I used without problem to support some Macs and PCs for a number of years (probably bought circa 2002).  I then moved to a house where it wouldn't work because the 3-pin sockets weren't grounded (ouch!), so it was out of use for about 18 months.  When I tried to use it in this house, it would not respond at all.

Is there anything sensible to do other than recycle the old one and buy a replacement?

(It's a 120V, 12A unit.)

Comment: I'll try to keep my soapboxing to a minimum, but I have had *universally* bad experiences with *everything* Belkin. While it's not surprising at all that a UPS not used for 18 months would have dead batteries, and I agree with the recommendation that you are probably better off just replacing the device, I'd go with an APC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the batteries is dead. I do not have a belkin, but I have changed batteries on a couple of old APC without a problem.

Comment: Replacing the battery - and finding the right battery to replace it - is probably harder work than it is worth.  There are no signs of life whatsoever, even over a period of a day or so.

Comment: All the small UPS's (3 different brands) I have opened have used the same type of battery and all but one was very easy to replace the battery on. The cost for the batteries was IIRC less than 25% of a new UPS. I did it for my personal use when my time didn't cost anything. But for work I usually buy a new UPS because I know it will work, and I also get some warranty.

Comment: Googling with the search term 'Belkin F6C650-USB-MAC UPS batteries' shows battery prices from about $18 to about $70.  Looking at the Belkin site, it is moderately clear that they do not do much in the way of UPS any more - they have just a couple of current products.  The APC web site can be a bit confusing; looking at BE750LM and it appears to be available only through distributors (but it is a Latin America model); go for BE750G and it is $99.  So, a new unit might be around 3 times the cost of a replacement battery ($33).

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable with taking out the battery, look into buying a small [desulphator](http://batterymart.amazonwebstore.com/BatteryMINDer-12117-12-Volt-1.3-Amp/M/B000P23HZS.htm).  I've read of people restoring "dead" batteries
with these.

It would be a decent investment, too, since you can use it to extend the life of any lead-acid battery you own (car, boat, motorcycle, etc.).

These aren't snake oil, either.  They're widely known in solar, and other home-power circles.

Of course, the UPS could be damaged, as could the battery itself, which the desulphator wouldn't help.  You say the UPS doesn't respond at all.  Every UPS I've had at least functioned as a decent power filter even with a dead battery.  Maybe yours is toast?

Comment: Some of the UPS's I have encountered didn't show any life when the batteries was completely dead, but worked when I replaced the batteries.

Comment: This one shows no signs of life at all, even after being connected for a day or so...it will probably be simpler just to recycle and replace.

Comment: @Jonathan: I have had the same problem. For me it worked when I replaced the batteries but that was with a UPS from APC. For me it was much cheaper to replace the batteries than to buy a new one. It is probably easier to buy a new one, that you know will work, but it will cost you 4-8 times more.